# Use of Writer monad

Tags: haskell

I see how the Writer monad allows one to produce a list of strings along with a set of computations, but what is the use of this? It seems very crude. There seem to be few examples of 'real world' use of Writer. What is this monad actually useful for, apart from didactic purposes?

Lack of examples seems to be one of the barriers to learning Haskell. It would be good if there was a comprehensive Haskell Cookbook to help. (So, is there such?)

Comment: I imagine it’s useful for logging in an otherwise-pure computation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Writer` in itself is IMO rather useless. Yes, "logging in an otherwise-pure computation" makes sense, but for a simple pure computation you'd have to rewrite everything to use monadic binds. The result won't be dramatically nicer than if you had just rewritten it to manually concatenate log information.

What's really useful however is to add a `WriterT`-layer to a monad stack you have anyway, so you get logging capability with almost no change to the definitions. This is what's done in "big powerful" monads like those used in Yesod and the like, but a `WriterT` can just as well be applied to any simple special-purpose monad you use.

Answer (score 6):

For real world use, you can see that it is being used in these projects:

- [Yesod](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/972efd0ca4bbb0fa891bef6738298bd3fe4e5441/yesod-core/Yesod/Core/Internal/LiteApp.hs#L51)
- [Persistent](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/da4d304b302da6ed9da3470985c6e1c76cd5b20f/persistent/Database/Persist/Sql/Types.hs#L105)
- [hs-webdriver](https://github.com/kallisti-dev/hs-webdriver/blob/c5651509bf9b8bcbdb4a2a795ceaf2c8d9730108/src/Test/WebDriver/Class.hs#L20)
- [Yaml](https://github.com/snoyberg/yaml/blob/f905d517076638ee46794a5b25150b7095e82100/Data/Yaml/Parser.hs#L12)
- [Esqueleto](https://github.com/prowdsponsor/esqueleto/blob/9ae12733600def671f209fc4ec9360ab731b25bd/src/Database/Esqueleto/Internal/Sql.hs#L62)
- [hspec](https://github.com/hspec/hspec/blob/23a31060d182985ac71e2d85e484b5b62dc49e06/hspec-core/src/Test/Hspec/Core/Spec/Monad.hs#L28)

and many more...

Once you start writing more code, you will find out that Writer monad or it's transformer version is indeed useful in a lot of real world scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

It is useful for any function that produces additional data, in addition to output. The 'real' useful part is that is a monad, and like all other monadic functions they are easy to combine into larger functions.

As for what they can be used for:

- Logging (Log sub parts of some computation)
- Serialization (Perform serialization while computing some result)
- Persistence (Perform computation while saving state on disk or some other storage)
- Probably other things depending on how creative you are

Comment: I last used it in a reinforcement learning program a bit like TD-Gammon. The exact type I was using was something like `WriterT (Endo [BoardState]) (State StdGen) NeuralNet`. The list of `BoardState`s was fed to a simple GUI so I could watch the games it was playing against itself.

Comment: The Writer monad is _not_ generally useful for logging since the results are not available until the end of the computation. See also: http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/02/streaming-logging.html

Comment: I don't need real-time logs as the computation happens, I need an after-the-fact explanation of why the computation ended up with the result it did. Writer is useful for that kind of logging.